# React Native - Using Props for Modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props, react-native-modal

I am trying to use modal on my application but I want to separated into different classes as App.js and /components/modal. The problem I encountered is I couldn't pass the props properly. Here is my codes.

I imported modal.

```
import InfoModal from '../components/InfoModal';
```

I created state.

```
state = {modalVisible: false}
```

The visible function on press.

```
    setModalVisible = (visible) => {
        
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
    }
```

Calling component.

```
render() {

const { modalVisible } = this.state;  

return ( 

<InfoModal visible= {modalVisible} />    

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(true)} ><Text style={styles.infoButton}>Info</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            )}
```

I didn't understand what prop should I set and how, to work it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a render method, I assume your App.js is a Class component.

You can create a state on the constructor like that

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: false,
        }
    }

// rest of the class
}
```

Your function for changing the modal's visibility should be like that

```js
setModalVisible = (visible) => {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
}
```

That's how you control the state on the App class.

And for your modal, you pass `App.state.modalVisible` as a prop.

```js
<InfoModal visible={this.state.modalVisible} />
```

When you use setState, all the components receiving that new value as a prop will properly update

Answer (score 0):

use state and method inside Modal component and toggle it by using modal reference.

Put

```
const { modalVisible } = this.state;
```

and

```
setModalVisible = (visible) => {
        
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
    }
```

in InfoModal.js

then use it like this

```
   render() {
    return ( 
        <InfoModal ref={(c)= this.infoModal=c }visible= {modalVisible} />  
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.infoModal.setModalVisible(true)} ><Text style={styles.infoButton}>Info</Text></TouchableOpacity>
)
```